# Perl glob returning false positive when trying to match specific file types

Tags: perl

I am trying to match either "program.log" or "program.log.gz" or both in a directory using glob but glob is returning both string to @array regardless if anyone of them exist.

I did

```
@array = glob ("$dir/program.{log,log.gz}");
```

And now @array contains

```
$dir/program.log
$dir/program.log.gz
```

regardless if they actually exist.

Seems like glob is just expanding the string and pass it to @array regardless if the file actually exist. Is this an intended behaviour for glob? If so how do I pass only filenames that exists to @array?

Comment: Just like in the shell, only `*` and `?` perform file system expansions. For example, `glob("{a,b}{c,d}")` will return `ab`, `ad`, `bc`, `bd` whether those files exist or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documented behaviour of [`glob`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob):

> If non-empty braces are the only wildcard characters used in the glob, no filenames are matched, but potentially many strings are returned. For example, this produces nine strings, one for each pairing of fruits and colors:
>
> `my @many = glob "{apple,tomato,cherry}={green,yellow,red}";`

If you wanted to pass only existing files to the array, you could use `grep` and a file test, such as `-e` (exists)

```
my @files = grep -e, glob ("$dir/program.{log,log.gz}");
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Not gonna lie, I didnt quite understand what the perldoc was saying when I read it through the first time.

Comment: @Xflkekw You're welcome. The perldocs can be tricky to understand at first, but they do contain a lot of useful information, so be sure to read them carefully.